# ASP.NET OnTextChanged method

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I have ASP.NET website, there is a page when user have to enter text in textbox and image should appear depends the text that is entered. Everything is working but image appears only when you press Enter, is there a way image to appear as you entering the letters not by pressing Enter?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="initials" runat="server" Width="50px" OnTextChanged="initials_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void initials_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if(this.initials.Text == "A") { prvwleft.ImageUrl = "~/Images/left/A1.jpg"; } 
}
```

Comment: Put some code which you have tried.

Comment: For `OnTextChanged' to work you must be outside of the textbox.

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="initials" runat="server" Width="50px" OnTextChanged="initials_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>

Code behind:

protected void initials_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.initials.Text == "A")
        {
            prvwleft.ImageUrl = "~/Images/left/A1.jpg";
        }
    }

---this is just a test

Comment: You code behind runs on the server so requires a postback, I presume you don't want to do a postback every time the user presses a key. You need to do this in javascript not in c# in the code behind file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call  **onkeypress** event in javascript like this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function tSpeedValue(txt)
    {  

        alert("hi");
        var at = txt.value;
        alert(at);

    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeypress="tSpeedValue(this)"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and if you want to call it in server side

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"   onkeypress="__doPostBack(this.name,'OnKeyPress');" ></asp:TextBox>
```

and in .cs page the code should be like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var ctrlName = Request.Params[Page.postEventSourceID];
        var args = Request.Params[Page.postEventArgumentID];

        if (ctrlName == TextBox2.UniqueID && args == "OnKeyPress")
        {
            TextBox2_OnKeyPress(ctrlName, args);
        }
    }



 private void TextBox2_OnKeyPress(string ctrlName, string args)
        {
            //your code goes here
        }
```

Comment: IMPORTANT: The above server-side technique works but causes the entire page to refresh for each character entered, not ideal in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

In asp.net, `OnTextChanged` event fires when you leave the focus.

In your case, you should go for `KeyDown` event.

Asp.net Textbox doesn't have server side `KeyDown` event, so we will have to do it using jquery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#initials').keypress(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "A") {
                $('#prvwleft').ImageUrl = "~/Images/left/A1.jpg"; 
            }
            else {
                $('#prvwleft').ImageUrl = "~/Images/left/A1.jpg"; 
            }
        })
    });        
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a way event to fire immediately as I enter the text, without leave the focus or press a key ?

Comment: `KeyDown` event is only way to achieve this, you can Ajax to not postback on every key pressed.